# Trying to include Rails helper library in module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, include, require

I have a module called `Sms` that I'm defining in `lib/sms.rb`. Within it, I have a method called `Sms.chunk` that uses the method `word_wrap`. This is part of the TextHelper library, so I am including it at the beginning of the module with `include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper`:

```
module Sms
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

  def Sms.chunk
  ...
  word_wrap
  ...
```

I am requiring this module during initialization with the line `require "sms"` in `config/initializers/additional_libs.rb`

I also have a Grape API class called TWILIO_API where I want to call `Sms.chunk`. However, when I do, I get `undefined method`word_wrap' for Sms:Module`. I have tried including the TextHelper library in the TWILIO_API class itself, and various other ways of including it, but have had no success.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that [wrap_word](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c5205041f65206a1490063b08915e7b2a2151a61/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb#L223) is an `instance method` , and you're invoking it from a class method `Sms.chunk`. Make it an instance method by dropping the `Sms.` part. For instance, the following works:

```
require 'action_view'
class Test
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
  def test_method
    word_wrap('Once upon a time')
  end
end
o = Test.new
p o.test_method # "Once upon a time"
```